# Multiplying limits of integration with constants

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, substitution

I found the value of this correctly as $\frac{\pi}{2}$;
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\int_\frac{1}{n+1}^\frac{1}{n}tan^{-1}(nx) dx}{\int_\frac{1}{n+1}^\frac{1}{n}sin^{-1}(nx) dx}$$
But the solution I saw to this makes a substitution of $nx=t$, thereby changing $dx$ to $\frac{dt}{n}$ and changing the arguments of arctan and arcsine to t. All this is fine, but they also change the limits in both integrals to ranging from $\frac{n}{n+1}$ to $1$.

Why and how is this done?

Comment: As $x$ varies from $\frac 1 {n+1}$ to $\frac 1 n$, $t=nx$ varies from $\frac n {n+1} to 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have substituted $t = nx$, you need to change the limits corresponding to the variable $t$

At $x = \frac1n $, $t = n\frac1n = 1$

and at $x = \frac{1}{n+1}$, $t = \frac{n}{n+1}$